# is there any simple way to make the python raw_input UI more like the bash UI?

Tags: python, linux, user-interface, raw-input

i am using raw_input() in a script to take a user input which needs to refined iteratively.

is there any way simple way to give it the familiar cursor functionality enabling cursor and (ideally) mouse support so that the left and right cursors scroll along the string and the up cursor brings up the previous entry?

thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of the [`readline`](http://docs.python.org/library/readline.html) module.

Answer (score 0):

you can benefit from bash-like history-list editing by wrapping cmd module.

http://docs.python.org/library/cmd.html